# How can I tell when a Moment Duration will be affected by daylight savings?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The actual wall clock duration of some moment durations will vary depending on the timezone of the moment they are added to. For other durations, the timezone of the moment they are applied to is irrelevant. For example:

`moment.duration("P1D")` is timezone dependent:

If I add duration this to a moment, then that will result in an advancement of a day in that moment's timezone, but the number of hours advanced could be 23, 24 or 25 hours.

`moment.duration("PT24H")` is not timezone dependent:

If I add duration this to a moment, then the advancement will always be 24 hours regardless of that moment's timezone.

Is there an easy way to determine whether a given moment duration is timezone dependent or not?

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, I've settled on

`duration.toISOString().indexOf('PT') === 0`

It feels a little hacky, but if the duration has only time units it would be unaffected by DST. Only Day and higher units are variable depending on the timezone.